# Firefox cache issue with my site

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I've started to build a site for a customer [www.ifixboilers.com](http://www.ifixboilers.com). It is a simple form based site, there are three options, when someone clicks on one of the options I use JS to change the CSS position of one of the forms. Once the form has appeared there are various parts of the form to fill out, BUT if they wish to return to the home page they can click the 'Return' button which uses JS to change the CSS to hide to form again, allowing them to select a different form or re-read the main page.

The problem lies with FireFox — when they click the return button, none of the front page is clickable. It's like the form is still there but not visible. It only becomes visible when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> a couple of times.

In all the other browsers this is not an issue? I have searched high and low reading many Stack Overflow posts about cache clearing — I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I haven't gone into it but I'm getting a JS error "form1 is undefined" in line 112

Comment: Simply refreshing (via F5) works for me after clicking the `Return` button, and as Pumbaa80 already mentioned, there's a JavaScript error when you switch back to the home page.

Comment: this technique for hiding your content and making the form appear is really bad - I'd suggest using a separate page for that.

Comment: @pumpaa80 i was unaware about that error, but i cannot see how there is an error?

Comment: @george katsanos im trying to make the site interesting otherwise i would have done it in HTML and php

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be interesting and well constructed..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the code in your question, otherwise it will not make any sense after you've fixed the code on your site. See [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get my JS to work properly was to change the `<a>` tags to `<input type="button">`, and then use css to style them.

The problem was with this

```
<ul>
<li id="fix"><a href="#" onclick="showF1();">fix</a></li><!--fixForm.html-->
<li id="serv"><a href="#" onclick="showF2();">serv</a></li><!--serviceForm.html-->
<li id="cont"><a href="#" onclick="showF3();">cu</a></li><!--contactUs.html-->
</ul>
```

FireFox treated the "#" as a page anchor and changed the url to www.ifixboilers.com/#, so changing the anchors to buttons solved my problem.

```
<div id="buttons">
<input type="button" name="fix" id="fix" onclick="showF1();" /><!--fixForm.html-->
<input type="button" name="serv" id="serv" onclick="showF2();" /><!--serviceForm.html-->
<input type="button" name="cont" id="cont" onclick="showF3();" /><!--contactUs.html-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that your form is still there above the buttons, just that it's opacity has been set 0. You should try to completely hide the form (like using CSS "display: none" property) at the end of the fadeOut animation.

Comment: hi abhijit, thanks for looking i tried your suggestion and it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry, mine was more of a suggestion as to how to fix the problem. Anyway, you can try adding `setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + objID + "').style.display = 'none';", delay);` as the last line in the `fadeOut` function. That should make it working, unless there is some other JS error. Again this is just a quick-fix, not the best solution.

Comment: And you should also add `document.getElementById(objID).style.display = 'block';` as the first line in the fadeIn function, otherwise the form will not show up once hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding any of these to your markup?

1. `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">`
2. `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-store">`
3. `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="must-revalidate">`
4. `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">`
5. `<meta name="expires" content="0">`

though FF3 will still be a problem.

Comment: i have just added it and it does not work, when i click any of the three buttons a hash appears after the url 'http://www.ifixboilers.com/#' it has something to do with that i think?

Comment: # appear because you have given href="#", I am not sure if that's the problem, try removing "#" from href.

Comment: if i remove the # the form will not appear

Comment: i may have figured out my problem, i am changing the <a> tags for <input type="button"> and so far it looks like its working.

Comment: That's great, any ways you should add these "no-cache" meta tags as caution.

Comment: Problem does not have anything to do with cache.

Answer (score 0):

Set z-index to -1 at the end of the animation or set display to none. Otherwise, you won't be able to click "through" the div.